# Is there a way to reload arraydata?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

```
$(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
    //url:"server.json",
    datatype:'local',
    //mtype:'GET',
    colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id',index:'id', width:55},
        {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90},
        {name:'name',index:'name asc, invdate', width:100},
        {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right"},
        {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right"},

        {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right"},

        {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}

    ],
    height:230,
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    pager: '#pager2',
    sortname: 'id',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption:"Array Example"
});
var mydata = [
        {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
        {id:"2",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
        {id:"3",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
        {id:"4",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
        {id:"5",invdate:"2007-10-05",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
        {id:"6",invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
        {id:"7",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
        {id:"8",invdate:"2007-10-03",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
        {id:"9",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}
        ];
```

for(var i=0;i<=mydata.length;i++)
    jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,mydata[i]);

$("#list2").jqGrid().clearGridData();
alert('reload'); 
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid().setGridParam({datatype: 'local'});
jQuery("#list2").trigger("reloadGrid");
});

I erased the data in the grid and then again it does not reload

What's wrong?

Comment: Try to give a description and clear the question.

Comment: I erased the data in the grid and then again it does not reload

Comment: If you erase the data in the grid and want to add the data again you should use `jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('setGridParam',{data: mydata});` to set the data one more time before your refresh the grid contain with `jQuery("#list2").trigger("reloadGrid")`. The call of `clearGridData` delete all information about previous added data. So your current code should show the empty grid only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should not clear the grid data with respect of `clearGridData` immediately after its filling (with respect of `addRowData`).

If would be better to fill jqGrid at the time of creation. To do this you should move the definition of `mydata` above the grid creation and add additional parameter `data: mydata` to the jqGrid. You should add one more jqGrid parameter `gridview:true` which improve the performance additionally. All other parts of code (`for` with `addRowData`, `clearGridData`, `setGridParam` and `reloadGrid`) should be just removed.

Comment: Your answers are very satisfactory.

Comment: The problem was resolved. for() is not required to output of value anymore.Thank you.

Comment: However, the value of the grid is a random output.
Even if use to {sortorder:"asc" or "desc"}.

Comment: @lee: What do you mean under "a random output"? You can compare your example with the http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGrid.htm for example. What problem exist?

Comment: Skipped {sorttype:'int'} in the colModel:[]. Sorry~.